# Is there any free software for Android that can send my geolocation to a web service?

Tags: android

Is there any free software for Android that can send my mobile phone's geolocation information to a Google map or to my own URL?

Answer (score 0):

Software...for your computer or your phone? If for your phone, then yes, there are a lot apps that do this. "Where's My Droid?" and Lookout Mobile Security can transmit your phone's location to a map on the internet. Also, as for Google Aps, there is Latitude. These all send the locations to their own maps on their websites(which I presume are, in fact, Google maps.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, is this - http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.sylvek.sharemyposition - what you want?

Generally, http://f-droid.org is the good place to start, when you need specifically free software (open-source) for Android.